# How to recursively `zip` all files of a certain type in a directory?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, zip

I want to use the `zip` command to create a .ZIP of a folder but only include `.txt` files.

Subdirectory structure should be preserved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're certain that none of the filenames will contain a newline then you can use `find`  as explained in the `zip(1)` man page.

```
find some/dir -type f -name '*.txt' -print | zip ... -@ ...
```

Comment: I'm afraid it specifically says MacOS X does not support this :(

Comment: It says "MacOS". OS X is Unix, not MacOS.